# Can't Reindex Catalog Search: 405 Not Allowed (Magento 2.4)

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, reindex, elasticsearch

My Catalog Search needs reindexing, but `sudo bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext` won't work and returns the following:

```
Catalog Search index process unknown error:
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I've seen other questions with a similar issue to mine, but none with this particular error. My Magento is using Elasticsearch 7.

**EDIT**: I deleted one product and tried again, and got the following error:

```
Catalog Search index process unknown error: 
<!DOCTYPE html>                             
<html lang="en">                            
<head>                                      
<meta charset="utf-8">                      
<title>Error</title>                        
</head>                                     
<body>                                      
<pre>Cannot PUT /magento2_product_1_v1</pre>
</body>                                     
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to prevent this exception from appearing in the current version of Magento 2 till the date, is to **use only an officially supported version of Elasticsearch (6.x or 5.x)**.

Elasticsearch 7.x is not supported by magento, the exception will appear everytime you rebuild the search indexes.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. ES7 is actually the only supported version currently: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html#elasticsearch

Comment: Yes you are right, but in magento 2.4 version, which magento version you are using?